# Meaning of 日本の風土

Tags: meaning

> **日本には日本の風土に合った教育も重要だ。**

I read from jisho.org that the definition of **風土** are: natural features; topography; climate; spiritual features.

While [dictionary.goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A2%A8%E5%9C%9F/) described it as: １ その土地の気候・地味・地勢などのありさま。２ 人間の文化の形成などに影響を及ぼす精神的な環境。「政治的風土」「宗教的風土」

I wonder what the meaning of **日本の風土** is when it was related to an education. Culture? Spirit?

Answer (score 10):

I'd translate it "cultural climate".

Personally, I don't think it's a very well-defined word, as I often see it used naively i.e. confuses geographical, biological, inherent conditions with sociological, acquired conditions when explaining a social phenomenon. I don't know whether yours is the case or not.